# Unwanted form size growing on TSplitter move when Panel1.Constraints.MinHeight is set

Tags: delphi, height, splitter, tform

I have this type of situation (see image), now when I move `Splitter1` up in run-time, `Panel2` height grows and also `Form1` height grows.

But I need to know and block this type of event, when `Splitter1` can't be moved up because of `Panel1.Constraints.MinHeight` is reached, so `Panel2` can't be changed of it's height and `Form1` too.

Thanks for any help.

[image: preview]

-- ***Edit*** --
`Panel1.Align` := alLeft;
`Splitter1.Align` := alBottom;
`Panel2.Align` := alBottom;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check and deny further sizing in splitter's `CanResize` event.

```
procedure TForm1.Splitter1CanResize(Sender: TObject; var NewSize: Integer;
  var Accept: Boolean);
begin
  Accept := ClientHeight - (NewSize + Splitter1.Height) >= Panel1.Constraints.MinHeight;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great for me. The simplest solution is the best.

Answer (score 1):

Set the Splitter AutoSnap property to false and its MinSize property to the MinHeight of Panel1.

Comment: I have `AutoSnap` set to False, and `ResizeStyle` set to rsUpdate. I'm sorry for not mentioning of this until now.

Comment: Then you seem to have missed to set the MinSize of the Splitter to the MinHeight of Panel1. Without that my solution will not work. Anyway, Sertac showed another valid approach.

Comment: No, I don't missed `Splitter1.MinSize` property. It is set to 84, this will be the min size of `Panel2` when moving `Splitter1` down.

Comment: Well, the trick is to set it to the MinHeight of Panel1 (i.e. 200). It may not be what is desired, but it is a workaround for that weird bug/feature in the TSplitter implementation. TSplitter.MinSize is checked for both ends. Sertacs solution is more flexible, though.

Comment: @UweRaabe - I find it also more reliable :) because if you change the Constraints of the panel then you have to REMEMBER to update also the MinSize property of the splitter.  (Hey! My Firefox spellchecker says that 'splitter' is not a valid english word!)